# jQuery: ¿Para qué sirven los métodos GET y POST en jQuery y cómo utilizarlos?

Tags: jquery

El objetivo de esta pregunta no es conocer la diferencia entre los métodos GET y POST de Http, sino el uso que debe darse a los mismos desde jQuery, o sea, cuándo usar uno u otro, en jQuery.

Y si es posible, ver algunos ejemplos de cómo se usan.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

El uso de GET o POST depende de lo que quieras hacer:

Usar GET sólo para operaciones que impliquen consulta/recuperación de datos siempre que valoremos que el cacheado en el navegador no causará problemas.

Usar POST para operaciones que impliquen modificación en el servidor (por ejemplo borrado de datos, actualización, etc.). También puede usarse POST para consulta/recuperación de datos.